# How to ensure connection.end() is called when obtaining a database connection from a pool

Tags: node.js, express, connection-pooling, node-mysql

We are using node-mysql and I'm exposing createPool of mysql where from any file, we can require the database file and obtain a connection like this

```
var db = ("./database");

db(function(err, connection) {
   //use connection to do stuff
}
```

I noticed that people don't always remember to call `connection.end()` that would return the connection to the pool and then we hit the limit..

How can I design the acquiring of the connection so that no matter when they decide to terminate the callback function that the connection.end() is called? I can't figure out a way to make a single place where we can do this so developers are only concerned with getting the connection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the createPool from mysql, but can't you just wrap it?

People will provide a `function stuff(err, connection) { ... do whatever they want ... }`.
Why don't you take that function and create a `save_stuff`-function? Something like

```
function save_stuff_creator(stuff) {
    return function(err, connection) { stuff(err, connection); connection.end() }
}
```

You maybe want some `try..catch` around the `stuff()`-call.

If you want the `connection` to stay with someone for some other callbacks, you could modify the function to something like `stuff(connection, callback)` and use a module like `async` and a `series`-Object.

But I have no idea how to enforce a final call of `connection.end()`if you want to wait for the end of "the user thread": that is actually the issue. There is no such thread and there is no way of figuring out which event in the event loop comes from whom. As far as I know the event loop is not exposed to the js-developer.

If you can't trust your callee, maybe you can put his code in an extra child node (see module `cluster`. So you have a bit of control: when the child finishes you become notified.